# Read metadata with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, timecodes

I'm looking for a way to print a video or audio file metadata using FFMPEG.

I tried the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i DirtyLove.mov
```

And got the following result:

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 16 2015 18:01:39 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.5.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --disable-indev=qtkit --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.2 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../DirtyLove/DirtyLove.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2007-09-27 11:23:38
  Duration: 00:01:57.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17918 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 720x576 [SAR 72:72 DAR 5:4], 14839 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-27 11:23:38
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire d�alias Apple
      encoder         : Photo - JPEG
      timecode        : 10:04:01:11
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-27 11:23:38
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire d�alias Apple
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-27 11:23:38
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire d�alias Apple
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-27 11:29:22
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire d�alias Apple
      timecode        : 10:04:01:11
At least one output file must be specified
```

There should be a `timecode` that I can't see.

Any ideas?

Comment: hey, next use the find in text feature ofany terminal, tet editor etc

Comment: Yes I guess I was tired when I ask this question... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-09-27 11:29:22
      handler_name    : Gestionnaire d�alias Apple
      timecode        : 10:04:01:11